# How to combile live video streams using VideoMixingRenderer9?

Tags: directshow

I want to combine multiple live streams in single stream. So my code will take multiple streams as input & after combining it will provide single stream as output.

I have created an application which takes multiple video files as input & shows them in single video.

Waiting for reply.

-Shashank

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get mixed output from the VMR is to implement a custom allocator/presenter. Then you will get access to the surface containing the mixed image for output.